# SwiftUI - Environment Object Not Updating UI

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, state, swiftui

My app has one button that produces either a green or red background. The user presses the button over and over to generate green or red each time and the results are recorded into an Observable Object called "Current Session." The current totals are displayed in a custom view made of capsules. For some reason, the view will not update the totals and keeps displaying 0.

I've tried adding a state binding for numberOfGreens in ResultsBar but that doesn't work either. It still just shows 0 every time. The environment has been added to all of my views. I've tried printing the results and the result numbers show up correct in the console but the UI will not update. Interestingly, the trialsRemaining variable works perfectly on other screens in my app, having no trouble updating when it has to. Also, ResultsBar works perfectly fine in preview.

```swift
class CurrentSession: ObservableObject {

  @Published var trialsRemaining: Int = 100
  @Published var numberOfGreens: Int = 0
  @Published var numberOfReds: Int = 0

  func generateGreenOrRed() {
    ...
    if resultIsGreen {numberOfGreens += 1}
    else if resultIsRed {numberOfReds += 1}
    trialsRemaining -= 1
  }
}
```

```swift
struct ResultsBar: View {
  let totalBarWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 48
  var onePercentOfTotalWidth: CGFloat { return totalBarWidth/100 }
  var numberOfGreens: Int

  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {       
      Capsule()
        .frame(width: totalBarWidth, height: 36)
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .shadow(radius: 4)   
      Capsule()
        .frame(width: (onePercentOfTotalWidth * CGFloat(numberOfGreens)), height: 36)
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .shadow(radius: 4)   
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
struct ResultsView: View {

  @EnvironmentObject var session: CurrentSession

  var body: some View {
    VStack {       
      HStack {
        Text("\(session.numberOfGreens)")
        Spacer()
        Text("\(session.numberOfReds)")       
      }

      ResultsBar(numberOfGreens: session.numberOfGreens)
    }
  }
}
```

I am running Xcode 11.2 beta 2 (11B44) on macOS Catalina 10.15.2 Beta (19C32e).

Comment: can you show the code for the button?

Comment: @Chris there's nothing really there except for a buttonPressed function that calls the function to generate green or red, and sets off a timer to disable the button for five seconds (all of which works fine).

Answer (score 5):

Are you passing a reference to a `CurrentSession` instance to your `ResultsView`? If I copy your code, the following does update the `ResultsBar` when I click on it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var session = CurrentSession()

    var body: some View {
        ResultsView()
            .environmentObject(session)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.session.generateGreenOrRed()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This led me to solving the problem! It wasn't what you said, it was actually about using the EnvironmentObject wrapper. I changed it to ObservedObject everywhere, and added the environment object to the end of the view body and now it works. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction.

Comment: in iOS 14 this solution breaks the app, DON'T DO IT!!!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, but my issue was because I was updating the environment object on a `background thread` because I'm using an api. In order to fix my issue I just needed to wrapped setting my EnvironmentObject vars like the following.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.numberOfGreens = GetNumberOfGreens(id: id)
}
```

I hope this helps someone.